# Django-CMS how to pass different data to each plugin separately?

Tags: django, django-cms

So I am querying  a service that will give me back a bunch of data in JSON. I have 5 different plugins that will take particular parts of that JSON in order to render content in their template.

I would like to know what is the best approach for doing 1 query and then passing the data from that query to each plugin?

In order to do the query I also need to grab query string parameters from the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach I have found is to use plugin context processors to pre-process each plugin.
Docs are here:
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#plugin-context-processors